Angular JS to Angular 18 migration
I'm trying to create a hybrid Angular JS Angular 18 application, and at first the application was running fine with this setup:
upgrade-module.ts
import { DoBootstrap, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myapp'], { strictDi: false });
  }
}

main.ts file:
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/upgrade-module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


and this in my index.html:
<body>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>

However, I tried added angular 18 components to test if they could also work in the hybrid application like this:
import { DoBootstrap, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { routes } from './app.routes'; // Ensure the correct path to your routes
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationUpgradeModule } from '@angular/common/upgrade';
// import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    LocationUpgradeModule.config({
      useHash: true,
      hashPrefix: '!'
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myapp'], { strictDi: false });
  }
}

routes:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularJsComponentComponent } from './angular-js-component/angular-js-component.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/hello', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'hello', component: AppComponent },
    { path: '**', component: AngularJsComponentComponent }
];


index.html:
<body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>

the template of the angularjs component is:
<div ui-view></div>

but now nothing is being rendered

Shouldn't it be.
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

This will render the angular components inside the body tag.
Also we need to import the app.component inside the module and bootstrap it.
import { DoBootstrap, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { routes } from './app.routes'; // Ensure the correct path to your routes
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationUpgradeModule } from '@angular/common/upgrade';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    LocationUpgradeModule.config({
      useHash: true,
      hashPrefix: '!'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myapp'], { strictDi: false });
  }
}

Finally in the app.component.html it should contain the router-outlet.
You have to create another component that will serve as a replacement for the component you defined on route hello.
...
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/hello', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'hello', component: SomeComponent },
    { path: '**', component: AngularJsComponentComponent }
];


I think it can work but i got this error:
✘ [ERROR] TS-996009: The AppComponent class is a standalone component, which can not be used in the @NgModule.bootstrap array. Use the bootstrapApplication function for bootstrap instead. [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/upgrade-module.ts:20:14:
  20 │   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
     ╵               ~~~~~~~~~~~~

The 'bootstrap' array is present on this NgModule.
src/app/upgrade-module.ts:9:0:
  9 │ @NgModule({


@Somed please remove standalone true and it should work

It works, but the angular js application is still not being rendered, if i go to /hello some component is rendered, but if i go to any other route i just get a white screen, but this console log i added is executed
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-angular-js-component',
template: '',
styleUrl: './angular-js-component.component.less',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AngularJsComponentComponent {
ngOnInit(): void { }
}

@Somed Try this approach on SomeComponent stackblitz ignore the ng-view in html
